# How to targeting table row with flot chart interactively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

I have flot bar chart and table that contains data series used by flot bar chart..
Each row represent one bar..
These are my html and js script:

```
<div class="flot-chart">
    <div class="flot-chart-content" id="flot-bar-chart"></div>
</div>
<!-- /.flot chart -->

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1354521600000</td>
            <td>1000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1355040000000</td>
            <td>2000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1355223600000</td>
            <td>3000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>1355306400000</td>
            <td>4000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>1355487300000</td>
            <td>5000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>1355571900000</td>
            <td>6000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- /.table -->

<script>
$(function() {
    var barOptions = {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 43200000
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%m/%d",
            minTickSize: [1, "day"]
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: "x: %x, y: %y"
        }
    };
    var barData = {
        label: "bar",
        data: [
            [1354521600000, 1000],
            [1355040000000, 2000],
            [1355223600000, 3000],
            [1355306400000, 4000],
            [1355487300000, 5000],
            [1355571900000, 6000]
        ]
    };
    $.plot($("#flot-bar-chart"), [barData], barOptions);
});
</script>
```

In this case, i need to make when each row of that table is hovered, the related bar will triggering highlight and tooltip just like when we hovering that bar directly on chart..

How the logic of javascript (jquery) to targeting table row with flot chart interactively base on script above?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you having problems? SO is not meant to give you solutions, but instead solve doubts. For mor info check [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you using Highcharts in your project?

Comment: Nope, i'm using Flot.js